# Wrong barcode exported from Visual Basic Macro in MS Word to PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I am trying to export through a Macro in MS Word a String that has 4 numbers. The whole Macro runs just fine, but, when I open the resulting PDF, I see that the barcode displayed seems corrupt.

This is the result:

[image]

In the Macro, I select the text I want to format, and change the font to "Free 3 of 9 Extended".

I have tried wrapping this number with "*" characters without success. Also tried "!". None of this seems to work. The funny part is that, if I open a Word document and type the same numbers using the same font, a clear Barcode is displayed:

[image]

This is what I see when writing directly in MS Word the same characters using the same font,this is what I see (which is what I want to achieve in the PDF export).

My macro exports to PDF with the following code:

```
Public Function guardar(id As String) As String
  Dim path As String
  guardar = id
  obj_Word.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=guardar, 
  OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, UseISO19005_1:=True, 
  IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
End Function
```

Comment: Please include the entire code involved in the problem. The macro that applies the format is missing. I also recommend you record a macro while typing and formatting manually then carefuly compare that with the code you already have. I seem to recall you mentioning in another post that you'd mistyped the font name, for example...

Comment: It would be helpful to know how the barcode was generated -- is in based on a font? is it an image placed in Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that the template you are given is setting the font weight to **bold** in that portion of the document in which you are introducing the barcode, thus modifying the way it is displayed?

I cannot think of any other reason. The code you are posting does not seem to be the culprit.

Comment: Spot on! I've checked the template and that bit of text was on bold . Changed it back to normal weight and the codebar is displaying nicely. Well spotted! Thanks!!!